# Adobe Acrobat auto dark mode feature for pdf files?

Tags: windows, github, windows-11, pdf-reader, dark-mode

Adobe Acrobat auto dark mode feature for pdf files?
I am using auto dark mode for my windows (github program), to switch to dark theme when it is night time, I want a program that switches the pdf files to dark mode also when using it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it automatically, but this is how I manually do it:

### Step 1:

Go to Edit --> Preferences --> Accessibility

Set `Custom Color` with dark background and white text.

Also unchecking '*Only change the color of black text or line art.*' worked really well for me.
[image]

### Step 2:

Go to View --> Display Theme

Set it to *Dark Grey*.

### Final Result Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat currently does not have any auto dark mode feature as you describe in the question. It only allows user to *manually* set dark mode.